# Python script not returning string

Tags: python

Hi I'm experiencing very weird phenomena.

I have 2 scripts.

1) `main.py`

```
import tree
def main():
   msg =tree.logic(data)
   print msg
```

2) `tree.py`

```
def logic(data):
    if data["A"] > data["B"]:
        return "A is bigger"
    else:
        return "B is bigger"
```

When I print `msg` in `main.py`, it just prints `None`. Disclaimer: A and B do not have same values. I checked it.

`data` example, it is just dictionary:

```
{
"A": 23,
"B": 25
}
```

Since it was not returning a string, I did one quick test like below. Withough having a if-statement in logic function, I just returned a string right away.

```
def logic(data):
    return "Is it returning?"
```

Then, `msg` printed `"is it returning?"`. I'm not sure why the string was not returned in the first case. Thoughts?

Comment: @cricket_007 added

Comment: @cricket_007 if it were undefined, shouldn't it exit with an error message "NameError: name 'data' is not defined"?

Comment: Put all your code into a single script and try it.  Post the entire single script in your question if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is for 2 different files in the same directory. I put the data in main() since you have a main() and data can't be passed into main(). If you want to pass data into a function when you start your program then the function has to called something other than main().

File 1: main.py

```
#!python2

# import module
import tree

def main():
    data = {"A": 23, "B": 25}
    msg = tree.logic(data)
    print msg

# start program
main()
```

File 2: tree.py

```
#!python2

def logic(data):
    if data["A"] > data["B"]:
        return "A is bigger"
    else:
        return "B is bigger"
```

Comment: Data **can** passed into main... I do it all the time. `if __name__ == "__main__":`... Then define data, then call `main(data)`

Answer (score -1):

main function should take data parameter.

```
import tree
def main(data):
    msg =tree.logic(data)
    print msg
```

Answer (score -1):

the main function is not being called and data isn't defined. It works (without any modification to tree.py) if you change main.py to the code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import tree

def main():
    data = { "A":4, "B":3 }
    msg = tree.logic(data)
    print msg

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```